# Can I create a symlink to a Windows executable in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) PATH?

Tags: command-line, java, jdk, symbolic-link, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Android Studio and JDK 8 installed on Windows, but the JDK cli isn't available on my WSL. When I type `java` or `javac`, the command isn't found. I followed the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53574705/7987987) and now I can reach the commands from WSL by typing `java.exe` and `javac.exe`, but I don't want to have to specify the `.exe` extension. My idea is to add a symlink that points to the executables, but without having to specify the path to the executable (`/mnt/c/...`) seeing as that's already been done in the WSL PATH. So can I create a symlink that points to a location in the PATH? If this doesn't make sense, this is what I tried:

```
sudo ln -s -t java.exe java
```

and I got `"failed to access 'java.exe': No such file or directory"`. Yet this is exactly what I want to achieve: a symlink to an executable in the PATH without specifying the actual path to the executable because PATH already has that. If I'm crazy and this is silly/impossible/unnecessary, you can say that as the answer and I'll accept it! :-D

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185086/bash-on-windows-alias-for-exe-files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to prefix the executable with its path. Alternatively you can modify the Linux `PATH` environment variable and append the Windows path (prefixed with `/mnt/c/`).

From: [Windows Subsystem for Linux interoperability with Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#run-linux-tools-from-a-windows-command-line)

> ### Invoking Windows binaries from WSL
>
> The Windows Subsystem for Linux can invoke Windows binaries directly
>   from the WSL command line. Applications run this way have the
>   following properties:
>
> 1. Retain the working directory as the WSL command prompt except in the scenario explained below.
> 2. Have the same permission rights as the bash.exe process.
> 3. Run as the active Windows user.
> 4. Appear in the Windows Task Manager as if directly executed from the CMD prompt.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $ /mnt/c/Windows/System32/notepad.exe
> ```
>
> In WSL, these executables are handled similar to native Linux
>   executables. This means adding directories to the Linux path and
>   piping between commands works as expected. Examples:
>
> ```
> $ export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32
> $ notepad.exe
> $ ipconfig.exe | grep IPv4 | cut -d: -f2
> $ ls -la | findstr.exe foo.txt
> $ cmd.exe /c dir
> ```
>
> The Windows binary must include the file extension, match the file
>   case, and be executable. Non-executables including batch scripts and
>   command like `dir` can be run with `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe
>   /C` command.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> $ /mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C dir
> $ /mnt/c/Windows/System32/PING.EXE www.microsoft.com
> ```
>
> Parameters are passed to the Windows binary unmodified.

Even in Linux symbolic links contain the path. Take for example this command:

```
$ ls -la /bin | grep ^l
(...SNIP...)
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      20 Jun 27 09:49 systemd -> /lib/systemd
```

`systemd` is linked to `/lib/systemd/systemd`. So your symbolic link of:

```
sudo ln -s -t java.exe java
```

I imagine (because I'm not a link expert) would need to look something like:

```
sudo ln -s -t /mnt/c/Windows/Path/To/java.exe java
```

---

### Use `alias` instead of symbolic link

Rather than a symbolic link I would create an alias in my `~/.bashrc` file thusly:

```
alias java='/mnt/c/WindowsPathTo/java.exe'
```

Then whenever you type `java` the mumbo-jumbo is typed on your behalf. Any parameters passed are honoured.

Comment: The alias should be first, but have a **+1** anyway... **;-)**

Comment: Rather late but @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks for your great and detailed answer! I ended up using the alias method. For anyone else wondering why it works, aliases apparently have higher priority than symlinks in bash, as explained in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132628/363992.

Comment: Aliases are hardly compatible with shell scripts. So here is my solution with helper script for quick symlink creation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185086/bash-on-windows-alias-for-exe-files/58156581#58156581

Comment: @Vadzim thanks for that! Ultimately I have decided to install the Linux versions of any executable, where possible. I can’t always predict which windows executable will work properly in WSL and which ones will throw unexpected errors due to incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Fish-Shell and found that both alias and symbolic links don't really work. I'm not sure if it's an issue with fish though, I rather suspect Windows' weird path naming is the problem.

My solution was to add a function to fish.config (the equivalent of .bashrc)

```
function npp
    "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" $argv
end
```

($argv in fish is the equivalent to $* in bash)

Then I can call Notepad++ via: `npp test.txt`